# How to get better error 400 error message for list item updates via REST?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am changing a lot of fields with a REST POST/MERGE request to a list item. When an input is wrong, is there a way to figure out WHICH field caused the 400 error? All I get is this useless response:

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "-1,     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": {
      "lang": "de-DE",
      "value": "Input string was not in a correct format."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately **NO**, I did not come across any way to identify which value has caused 400 bad request error.

Workaround is to remove column & respective input one by one and check the fields for which you need to make the input in proper format.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ravi that there isn't any way I know of to get more information, but there is a bit of information there. It mentions **input string** so one of the columns in the list is expecting a string and either you've mangled a string or your trying to pass a number, boolean, or other value.

First instinct is usually to look at the data that is marked as string, but often the problem is the other way -- something in your passed data that should be a string, but isn't. So look at your list and see that all the ones that are string types are actually being passed in your code as strings.

There is also the [Unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244176/i-got-this-error-an-unexpected-primitivevalue-node-was-found-when-reading-fro) error which means that you've passed a primitive (simple) value when it is expecting a collection-type object.